# Get Registered HttpHandlers in the Web.Config from HttpContext

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to get the types of the registered `IHttpHandler`s from a current `HttpContext` or the web.config?

I'm trying to see if my `HttpHandler` is registered in the web.config from a `WebControl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the list of registered `HttpHandler`s from web.config this way:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

Configuration cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
HttpHandlersSection hdlrs = (HttpHandlersSection)cfg.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers");
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work for custom handlers. Running the code above I get all the stock handlers, but my custom handlers are not showing up in the handler list. Also you need to check (system.webServer/handlers) depending on whether the app is running on IIS 7 or previous.

Comment: To clarify what Rick is saying, this does not work for IIS 7.  However I can confirm this does work for IIS 6.