# How can you see the collection of registered httphandlers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, httphandler

How can you see which HttpHandlers are registered?
How can you loop through the registered HttpHandlers? I suppose all the handlers are in a collection somewhere but where.

Comment: can you expand a bit? what are you trying to handle? httphandlers are defined in the `httpHandlers` section of your `Web.Config` is that what you are after?

Comment: Is this the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083911/get-registered-httphandlers-in-the-web-config-from-httpcontext ?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

Configuration cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
HttpHandlersSection hdlrs = (HttpHandlersSection)cfg.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers");
```

just copied from here: [Get Registered HttpHandlers in the Web.Config from HttpContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083911/get-registered-httphandlers-in-the-web-config-from-httpcontext)

Answer (score 0):

From a web application, you can get the section with one line using the ConfigurationManager.

```
HttpHandlersSection httpHandlers = (HttpHandlersSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers");
```